# Flying domestically in the US, is my State Issued ID all I need to get past security?

Tags: usa, air-travel, domestic-travel

Is there anything else I need other than my state issued ID to get past security?

Answer (score 21):

You need a [TSA-approved ID](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) and a boarding pass (printed or on a mobile device).  That is all.

State driver's licenses and IDs are approved, but see the link for REAL ID rules that will apply after May 3, 2023.